# Kubernetes multiple pods communication

Tags: kubernetes

I explain my case.

I have three pods running in my Kubernetes.
In one pod, there is a Flask framework running. In the two other pods, there is a Java application with a REST API. ( The Java application is the same on the two pods ).

My pod with Flask has to ask the two pods with the Java application **individually** using HTTP requests.

I have created a service that points toward my two pods with Java Application.
When my pod with Flask uses the service to ask the two others, I just have one response.

How could I target my pods individually ? Is it possible in my case to get endpoints from the pod with Flask ? I could have x pods with my Java Application.

Best regards,

Nico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, the right way to do this is to have 3 [deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) each managing your pods individually each with a `replica` of `1`.

- One for your Flask app
- One for your Java app
- Another one for the same Java app.

If the Java apps are the only ones that you need to connect to from the Flask app you can expose those deployments with 2 different [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) that will manage the endpoints. Services are supposed to manage the endpoints unless you are trying to connect to an [external](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors) endpoint.

Comment: All my requests are internally. So I think services are what I need.

Following this way, if I scale up my pods with the Java App ( in this moment I just have 2 pods with the Java app, but in the future, I could need 5 pods with my Java app ), I will need to create additional services ? I need to contact every pod with Java app individually from my pod with Flask.

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

- you can get endpoints separate for your pods `kubectl get ep --all-namespaces`
- you dont need a k8s service if you are accessing things internally , you can use endpoints directly , but this is not recommneded , as the pods maybe re-created by RS
- therefore , in this case you can define two clusterIP services for these pods , given that you have labeled your pods differently

Comment: How can I get the endpoints being inside a pod ?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: you can get the endpoints anywhere , when you have kubectl and kubeconfig available

Comment: Is it a good pratice to have kubectl and kubeconfig inside a pod ?